# Trying to build a JavaScript grading program

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm new to JS and Jquery and i'm currently learning from a book and i'm trying to put it into practice by building a little grading program.

I want to have input boxes and depending on the number put in the box the color changes. However I think i'm going about it the wrong way as i'm using the class '.result' to target the change of the background color so whatever the first number is it changes all the elements with the class 'result'.

Another problem i'm having and don't see what i'm doing wrong is, the background color changes if i use

```
.getElementById('grade').value;
```

But it doesn't change the background color at all if I use

```
.getElementByClassName('grade').value;
```

Here is a link to what i'm working on, I hope I've explained my problems clearly and any help or advice would be appreciated.

https://jsfiddle.net/michaelgriffin87/m9v5xsbp/9/

Comment: You should not recycle IDs in your document—they must be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The working solution....

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <input class="name" placeholder="A Student name"></input>
  <input id="grade" class="grade result"></input>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <input class="name" placeholder="A Student name"></input>
   <input id="grade" class="grade result"></input>
</div>
 <button class="submit" onClick="checkGrade()">Button</button>
</div>
```

**Pure Javascript**

```
window.checkGrade = function(){
  var gd = document.getElementsByClassName('grade');
  for(var i = 0; i < gd.length; i++){
    var g = document.getElementsByClassName('grade')[i].value;
    var g1 = document.getElementsByClassName('grade')[i];
    if(g >=80) {
      g1.style.backgroundColor = "green";
    }else if(g >=60) {
      g1.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    }else if(g >=40) {
      g1.style.backgroundColor = "orange";
    }else if(g >=0) {
      g1.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }else {
      g1.style.backgroundColor = "pink";
    }
  }

}
```

Check out this [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/esgv59b8/)

Comment: Oh wow! this is exactly what i was trying to do... so the best thing to do is a loop with the if statement inside it. I'll have to retype this code and learn it. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is no `getElementByClassName` - there is the plural `getElementsByClassName`

```
.getElementsByClassName('grade')[0].value;
```

That will grab the value of the first node in the DOM that has the class `grade`, for example.

If you're using jQuery, you probably want something like this instead to affect all nodes with the `grade` class:

```
var $grades = $('.grade');

$grades.each(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor', foo);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A problem I see right off the bat is `.getElementByClassName` This should be `.getElementsByClassName` (notice the s - element**s**). It then returns an array so you'll need to loop the through the objects and grab the value from each one.